# When the Hazelcast support Jakarta EE migration to run on Tomcat 10 web server?

Tags: hazelcast, tomcat10, jakarta-migration

Our application needs to support Tomcat 10.
We are migrating the code to Jakarka EE 9, but due to HazelCast we are blocked.
When can we expect the HazelCast jakarta EE migration??

Details:
We are evaluating to support Tomcat 10 in our product. To start it, we initially try to use Servlet 5.0 spec as Tomcat 10 supports Servlet 5.0 specification.

The Servlet 5.0 version migrated the classes to Jakarta.servlet.* from javax.servlet.*. So, most of our java code have been migrated to Jakarta EE9.
But, in the middle we come to know that the HazelCast versions not compatible with Jakarta EE.
The internal classes of HazelCast still references to javax.servlet.* from Servlet 3.0 specification.
So as a result, we got compile time issues as well.

Does the HazelCast compatible with Tomcat 10??

Comment: Could you please also add why hazelcast is a blocker? What is missing with hazelcast?

Comment: The Jakarta EE9 namespaces changed from javax.* to jakarta.*. So any references to javax.* in hazelcast will have runtime issues.

Ex: javax.security.*   -------------> jakarta.security.*
javax.servlet.*   ------------------> jakarta.servlet.*

Comment: no news since 6 monthes ?

Comment: The upcoming HZ 5.4 is going to use jakarta namespaces.

Comment: What is the tentative timeline for HZ 5.4 open source release?